# Is being punative to new users a bad thing? How can it be avoided?

Tags: new-members, disciplinary-actions

I've noticed that on Stack Exchange especially, new users will often will often have their posts closed and downvoted, at I think, a higher level/severity than users with more reputation.

Often this will be because the post is showing up in the first posts review queue.

But more generally - often new users are quite obvious in any community, often they don't have the formatting down pat, or they have a low post count.

Is there any guidelines for maintaining high post quality, while still encouraging new users?

Comment: I believe this is a [duplicate](http://moderators.stackexchange.com/q/440/78) question.

Comment: Just as a comment: this doesn't seem all that unnatural to me; users with more reputation don't tend to ask the same low-quality, poorly-formatted and inadequately-researched questions that first timers do. With any luck, the new user learns from this and becomes a more productive member.