# Handling new users who don't read the rules

Tags: user-behavior, rules-and-policies, new-members

I moderate a community on a site that allows users to queue YouTube videos and songs while chatting.

Our room has set rules on what videos users are able to play and videos breaking our rules are skipped and the broken rule is sent in chat. After a user plays videos that break the rules multiple times, they are temporarily banned.

The problem is with new users who don't read the rules, and after we skip them, some users get angry and spam/insult, forcing us to mute them, and these users usually leave. Our database says that they rarely come back.

We've been thinking that this is a bit too harsh on new users and that it affects our community negatively.

How should we handle new users, who don't read the rules, so they don't leave, while we still enforce the rules?

Comment: Simply, if user not following rules then prompt then to read rules and count no of prompts, after 3 or 4 times same then suspend or delete user and band his IP

Comment: Related: http://moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/440/what-are-techniques-that-encourage-new-members-to-familiarize-themselves-with-co

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At some point, bending over backwards for new users is tiresome. However I suggest taking into account a few things

1. How disruptive are these users to *existing* users
2. How much of a burden is reading the rules to a new user? If they're simple and well written there's no excuse.

In this situation I'd consider a few things

1. Gentle reminders linking to the rules.
2. 'Sushing' new users so they can watch but not comment for a period of time. Think of it as a timeout.
3. Put new users in a separate area if they break the rules in the main one. If it's still broken, suspend them longer. *Good* behavior lets them play with the grownups.

At some point though, you need to consider if these *new* users are worth keeping if they annoy *existing* users.

Comment: +1. Good points, but we unfortunately don't control the site's software, thus we can't control users in every possible way. We could make our room bot do most of this, though.

This is the best answer so far and I'm going to mark it as accepted, but I encourage people to still add new answers.

Answer (score 3):

Whether this is feasible or not will depend on how much (if any) control you have over the site's software, but you could restrict the ability to queue videos to "established" users.

You need define "established" - this could be age of account, number of posts etc. Hopefully, when they've been around for long enough to be earn the privilege of posting videos, they'll be more aware of what the rules are. Also by framing this as a privilege it makes it easier to it take away from people (either temporarily or permanently) when they break the rules.

Comment: We have very little control over the site's software, but the site defines a good API with which we can make an automated bot control the room with more detail than us, humans can.